# Type error when using Extract to narrow a union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to narrow the return type of my `EthereumViewModel.getCoinWithBalance` by using the `Extract` utility type to take part of my `FlatAssetWithBalance` union based on `EthereumViewModel`'s generic `C` type (which is constrained to `'eth' | 'polygon'`), but it doesn't seem to overlap with the types of my `getAsset` function and therefore results in an error on the `return` line of my `getCoinWithBalance` function.

How can I change my `getCoinWithBalance` and or `getAsset` functions so that the types correctly overlap, and can you explain why they don't currently overlap?

You can see this example on the TypeScript Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHmAhgOwCYCUIGMCuAnAZwEsA3CAGxAB4AVAPigF4oaoI5gI0CoB7AIwBW2YACgoUAPws2HLqh5FkAMwh4oAeSlQA3lADaAaShKoAawgheyzQF0AXLAQoM2fMTKUqGo7YYBfKEdkCDI8cSCWAG4I0VBIKABhAAtEJQBJVCYoACIIYGScqAAfXP5gLCLSnLBeSgBzXmQcmPjoGAK1CBwAWxS05Ezs+CxyHFQIKn6M1AAaMoqcuhi48GgAIXJeLDMsVIyVXmydCIk9gczHHPLKmMDSk4kz-cHUK-zCmKeoLCbgPEQWGAjgI-yU9TuJV0px+L0uuVqDSaLRhv2Q-0BwKgoLw4LuolWCXgGKB02QVAAgrJONwoJttrs4Yd5olqfIeGTMgxmMSAUDKfM9OcZo5Wf5lgS2nTEAQIBSCLLgMcYchED0ICCwcgITCCCAevw6prcdqvk8iKhJMFevw1FCcGgIMolBBUGaJEQeoh6hArditfV7Y7nSE3TCAcgzH7kDa7aUHRMQ673VAJlhPYhyARrQa1Cm1bwHViY7m8PjCdAAGLkRDAeWKgDqRAK60zKCw0GYrdl9fyUAAZNDvsLXlcbij7tKewq+4OTgBINEkrE4vGouFvXIfCdQ7tymdKueov58lcBlMj+E1OogRrNctSjrJMnV2u94BNltt5AdqZs2lPl0vScqg3JOMuZJUK+dYHp+yStjWP4QCyEqPgUL41jBjbNvB34djQECgsM6EvNB75wQh7aTAA5Iit5NNRyxQASaY1ng0BokRPpYfkjh-uwNIKLAnTscBG50AAFJem6JAAlEwDB7u+A66LCFwyVEPwnpixp4lA-grKMMo8IBok9AAakQEAAO4ALK8BM5D8XIAEid0fTidCi4bqK2TUR81FQDKSSaQA9KFUAAFI4ERyi8OonTYogFh8DYnCguCBLztxiS8EoFF4RAEmyY4T4YW+sE4ZRSFTAwC7zuxwD4MgUDce+EkFEQBAAHTSbJMTzv4oj+EAA), but I have also copied the code and error message below.

```
type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object
  ? T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: ExpandRecursively<O[K]> } : never
  : T;
  
type ChainId = "eth" | "btc" | "polygon";
type EthereumChainId = Exclude<ChainId, "btc">;

type BlockchainInfo = {
    chainId: "btc";
} | {
    chainId: "eth";
    contract: string;
} | {
    chainId: "polygon";
    contract: string;
}

type ExtractChain<A extends BlockchainInfo, C extends ChainId> = Extract<A, { chainId: C }>;

type BaseAsset = {
    name: string;
    symbol: string;
    id?: number | undefined;
    image?: string | undefined;
    rank?: number | undefined;
    decimals: number;
    amount: number;
}

type FlatAssetWithBalance = BaseAsset & {
    chainId: "btc";
} | BaseAsset & {
    contract: string;
    chainId: "eth";
} | BaseAsset & {
    contract: string;
    chainId: "polygon";
}

type EthChainFlatAssetWithBalance<C extends EthereumChainId> = ExtractChain<FlatAssetWithBalance, C>;
type EthChainFlatAssetWithBalanceTest = EthChainFlatAssetWithBalance<'polygon'>; 

declare const getAsset: <C extends EthereumChainId>(chainId: C) => BaseAsset & { chainId: C; contract: string; };

class EthereumViewModel<C extends EthereumChainId> {
    chainId: C = 'eth' as C; // Just for the sake of testing

    getCoinWithBalance(): EthChainFlatAssetWithBalance<C> {
        // the below line is where the type error displays
        return getAsset(this.chainId);
    }
}
```

Here's the full error thrown from the return line of `getCoinWithBalance`.

```
Type 'BaseAsset & { chainId: C; contract: string; }' is not assignable to type 'EthChainFlatAssetWithBalance<C>'.
  Type 'BaseAsset & { chainId: C; contract: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Extract<BaseAsset & { contract: string; chainId: "polygon"; }, { chainId: C; }>'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your generic `C` type, although constrained to your `EthereumChainId` type (`'eth' | 'polygon'`) is not necessarily only one of the types from that union. It may include both `'eth'` and `'polygon'`.

This causes an issue with the return type of `getCoinWithBalance` because the return type of `getAsset` never returns a union, but the `Extract` type (used by `getCoinWithBalance`) can return a union of `BaseAsset & { contract: string; chainId: "eth"; } | BaseAsset & { contract: string; chainId: "polygon"; }` (because `C` may include both chain IDs).

To fix your code, you simply need to update the return type of `getAsset` to use the same `Extract` utility type e.g.

```
declare const getAsset: <C extends EthereumChainId>(chainId: C) => ExtractChain<FlatAssetWithBalance, C>;
```